# Windows Media Player - Enable play button without OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, windows-media-player

this is probably pretty simple, but I've noticed that when trying to start the Windows Media Player (AxWMPLib), it takes the "player.url = path", and only then does the player's Play-button get activated. Thing is, I want to play sound files taken from the URL of a column in a database. And when clicking on that row, the mediaplayer should update, making it's play-button clickable.

Any ideas?

Comment: "the URL of a column in a database" : what does that mean ??

Comment: Oh, just badly expressed from my part sorry.
What I meant was that the URL lies in a column in the database, as just plain text. But I managed to solve it by setting the autoplay property to false :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed the problem by setting the WMP's "autoplay"-property to false.